# gRPC over http/2 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-cloud-platform, grpc

Using Grijjy's TgoHttpClient [http/2 client](https://github.com/grijjy/DelphiScalableClientSockets) component, I am trying to connect to Google Cloud Speech over http/2. This component uses [nghttp2.dll](https://nghttp2.org/) for http/2 handling.

Unfortunately, Google does not respond (at least, TgoHttpClient.OnRecv is not triggered).

When I create a TgoHttpClient that does not use http/2, everything works, but that prevents sending/receiving real-time streaming audio and recognition results.

Anyone who got Google Speech to work using http/2 and nghttp2.dll, or who knows where to find detailed samples, maybe in other languages?

Regards,

Ronald

Code:

```
 const
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_STREAMING  = 'https://speech.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.Speech/StreamingRecognize';

var
  Gc: TgoHttpClient;
  Ps: TBytesStream;
  b1,b2: TBytes;
  n1,n2: Integer;

begin
         Ps := TBytesStream.Create; 
    //changing first parameter to False makes everything work!
          Gc := TgoHttpClient.Create(True, False); 
        
          with Gc do
          try
            Authorization := 'Bearer ' +  MyGCPAuthenticator1.AccessToken;
            RequestHeaders.AddOrSet('content-type', 'application/grpc');
            RequestHeaders.AddOrSet('user-agent', 'grpc-delphi/0.1.0-dev');
        
            OnRecv := DataReceived;
        
    //stream contains request config and audio in gRPC format
            Ps.Clear;
            Ps.Write([0] + BytesOf(@n1, SizeOf(n1)) + b1, 1 + SizeOf(n1) + Length(b1));
            Ps.Write([0] + BytesOf(@n2, SizeOf(n2)) + b2, 1 + SizeOf(n2) + Length(b2));
            Ps.Position := 0;
        
            RequestData := Ps.Bytes;
        
            if not Post(GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_STREAMING, b1) then
            begin
              raise Exception.Create(ResponseStatusCode.ToString);
            end;
          finally
            HttpClientManager.Release(Gc);
          end;
end;
```